# In what folder are all the forms and classes saved in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I cannot find the address where my project's files are stored. Can you tell me where to find them as i would like to copy them onto my pendrive so as to run them on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, by default Netbeans stores the projects within your documents folder: `\Documents\NetBeansProjects`. If memory serves, on Linux they are within the `~/Netbeans Projects` directory.

Alternatively, you can view your project's file structure by using the `Files` view, available on your left hand side (if not, you can activate it by going to `Window -> Files`.

Once that you have accessed this view, you can right click on any one of the nodes and select `Open Project of Folder` (if you ask me it should be the other way round, but anyways).